# Run NodeJS server with ES6 feature

Tags: node.js, babeljs, transpiler

I use NodeJS 0.12.7 version.
I have a question related launch NodeJS server with ES6 feature.
I need to transpile node_modules packages from ES6 to ES5 to run NodeJS.
How can I do it?

Comment: Node understands es6

Comment: I use 0.12.7 version

Comment: upgrade node to latest or LTS version

Comment: Using `0.12.7` in a current project is a bad idea. Please upgrade to a modern LTS release.

Comment: Node.js 0.12.7 is ancient.  Upgrade to node version 8.x or 10.x which natively support ES6.

Comment: You can try babel-node but there's no guarantee that it will work with 0.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack to transpile the code to commonJs which is understandable by node. Here is a webpack config link - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/fortjs-javascript-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js

You can use fortjs starter template which provides the setup ready to use. Take a look at this article of creating rest api in es6 - https://medium.com/fortjs/rest-api-in-nodejs-using-es6-227765440b2b